# Poner botón ATRÁS a un collapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

Bueno he estado trabajando con un ejemplo de collapsingToolbar. Bueno el detalle que tengo es que lo estoy implementando en una aplicación.

Sucede que desde mi actividad principal mando llamar una actividad en dicha actividad que mando llamar cuento con un collapsingToolbar, bueno todo funciona muy bien solo que no puedo dar ATRÁS por que el collapsinToolbar no me genera un botón atrás.

he intentado de todo.

por ejemplo  declarar el toolbar desde la actividad que contiene el  collapsintoolbar, lo que hice fue poner estas tres lineas en el onCreate de la actividad que contiene el collapsintoolbar... y bueno una vez que las pongo genero una nueva apk y la instalo y lo que sucede es que al seleccionar la actividad que tiene el collapsintoolbar, la aplicacion se cierra sin siquiera entrar a la actividad del collapsintoolbar.

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

*Con el código que dejo abajo selecciono la actividad que tiene el collapsintoolbar y me abre la actividad con el collapsintoolbar solo no me pone la flecha de retroceso en el collapsintoolbar. GRACIAS.*

**Codigo java de la actividad principal**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.herprogramacion.alquileres.provider.Contrato.Alquileres;

public class ActividadListaAlquileres extends AppCompatActivity implements       AdaptadorAlquileres.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private RecyclerView listaUI;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private AdaptadorAlquileres adaptador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_lista_alquileres);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Filtro...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Acción", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Preparar lista


    listaUI = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista);


    listaUI.setHasFixedSize(true);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    listaUI.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    adaptador = new AdaptadorAlquileres(this, this);


    listaUI.setAdapter(adaptador);


    // Iniciar loader
   getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_lista_alquileres, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(AdaptadorAlquileres.ViewHolder holder, String idAlquiler) {
   // Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), ":id = " + idAlquiler,
     //       Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, Alquileres.URI_CONTENIDO, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (adaptador != null) {
        adaptador.swapCursor(data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
}
}
```

**Codigo java donde genero el collapsintoolbar**

```
package com.herprogramacion.alquileres;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class biografia2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_biografia2);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Titulo ");


}
}
```

**codigo xml de mi actividad principal**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.herprogramacion.alquileres.ActividadListaAlquileres">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/contenido_actividad_lista_alquileres" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/icono_filtro" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**codigo xml de la actividad donde genero el collapsintoolbar**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/jack"
                android:alpha="0.5"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Related"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorContraste</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.CardContent" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```html
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/iconoapp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ActividadListaAlquileres"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".provider.ProviderApartamentos"
            android:authorities="com.herprogramacion.alquileres"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name=".biografia1">
            android:parentActivityName=".ActividadListaAlquileres" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.herprogramacion.alquileres.ActividadListaAlquileres" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".biografia2">
            android:parentActivityName=".ActividadListaAlquileres" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.herprogramacion.alquileres.ActividadListaAlquileres"

                />

        </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trata algo así en tus actividades secundarias:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    setSupportActionBar(collapsingToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }
}
```